# Como extrair json de um jsonp numa string em Scala

Tags: json, string, scala, jsonp

Estou usando Scala e tenho uma resposta http como essa:

```
_SS_MainSolrCallbackH(
  {
    response: {
      numFound: 1,
      start: 0,
      maxScore: 4.9338827,
      docs: [
        {
        tipo: "M",
        id: "mus1933196",a
        s: 4.9338827,
        u: "daniellaalcarpe",
        d: "lagrima-de-amor",
        dd: "",
        f: "202114_20130510215437.jpg",
        a: "Daniella Alcarpe",
        t: "Lágrima De Amor",
        g: "MPB"
        }
      ]
    },
    highlighting: {
      mus1933196: {
        titulo: [
          "Lágrima <b>De</b> <b>Amor</b>"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
)
```

Se eu tentar parsear essa string como json, vai falhar, porque não é exatamente um json. Qual é a melhor maneira de remover a parte `_SS_MainSolrCallbackH( )` da string, deixando apenas o hash json?

Comment: Olá, Daniel. Essa parte que você quer remover é sempre igual ou parecida? Já pensou em usar apenas `substring`?

Comment: na verdade é sempre igual, mas queria fazer de forma genérica. Eu resolvi temporariamente com string.replace("_SS_MainSolrCallbackH(", "").take(string.size - 2) mas parece meio feio...

Answer (score 1):

Fiz uma breve pesquisa e não encontrei um procedimento "canônico", senão manipulação de texto.

Sim, é um pouco feio, mas pelo menos você pode encapsular o comportamento em uma função/método. Então, se a especificação mudar, bastará ajustar a rotina.

Abaixo, um exemplo de função genérica que recupera o trecho da String entre a primeira e a última chave:

```scala
def toJson(jsonp: String): String = {
    jsonp.substring(jsonp.indexOf('{'), jsonp.lastIndexOf('}') + 1);
}
```

### [Demo no IdeOne](http://ideone.com/ycRPq8)

Answer (score 0):

No seu post do stackoverflow em inglês a solução correta (em termos de elegância e utilização boa dos recursos do framework) é a que propôs esse trecho em scala

scala> val body = "_SS_MainSolrCallbackH(\n\n)"
body: String = 
_SS_MainSolrCallbackH(

)

scala> val jsonStr = body.lines.toList.tail.init.mkString
jsonStr: String =

o crédito é do respondente no [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25246833/how-to-extract-json-from-a-jsonp-string-in-scala)